# Two style.css are conflicting

Tags: html, css

I have main style.css and the one provided with third party

```
// Include main CSS
<link charset="utf-8" media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://test.style-hunters.ru/wp-content/themes/style-hunters/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

// Include third party CSS, we have put it to css folder
<link href="http://test.style-hunters.ru/wp-content/themes/style-hunters/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In the second style.css

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

This makes all body elements to have padding.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Because second css file overwriting to first one. Because of this you have to delete `padding : 20px;` line from second css file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three good options, two of which are mentioned:

1: Use the !important flag. This is the least desirable, because you forever overwrite the padding rule--what if a page needs to overwrite it?

```
body { 
    padding: 0 !important; 
}
```

2: Flip the order; put the third party style sheet first.

3: Use the html tag:

```
html > body { 
    padding: 0; 
} 
/* OR */ 
html body { 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

If don't you care about IE6, use the first, if you do, use the second.

Answer (score 9):

Include the third party CSS file first so that you can override undesirable rules in your own file.

Answer (score 1):

if you add !important after the rule it will override other rules regardless of order.

```
body{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because second css file overwriting to first one. Because of this you have to delete `padding : 20px;` line from second css file.

If you can't edit second css file you can add `!important` to first css file. I mean like this :

`padding : 0 !important;`

Answer (score 1):

In your first CSS file:

```
html body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Add more selectivity to your styling rules.

Answer (score -1):

Don't flip the order bcos in that case other attributes of the second css file can be overwritten by the first css file. So uuse the **important** flag.

Comment: The !important tag should only be used as an absolute last resort, and in this case if changing the order is not acceptable using specificity is a much safer solution.